# Set Style for @Html.Pager in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, pager

i want to use MvcPager library in Asp.net mvc for my pager list
my Html Theme pager have class for style and i want to set this class for pager create with @Html.Pager(...)

Html Theme Pager code

```
<li><a href="#" class="tran3s"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="active tran3s">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="tran3s">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="tran3s"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
```

[image: and Html Theme pager image]

and library code for create pager is

```
@Html.Pager(6, Model.CurrentPage, Model.TotalResult)
```

[image: and MvcPager image]

Comment: any one can't answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

I find it
i inspect element the paging create with @Html.Paging(...) and find what is the tag class and create style for it in my style.css